# Angular-CLI: How to import SCSS variables into JavaScript

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm writing an Angular 2 component to create a custom grid layout. The SCSS variables are in a SCSS file called `_variables.scss`. I'd like to get access to these variables in JavaScript. I noted a few npm tools, such as [scss_to_json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-to-json), but have no idea how to implement that in an Angular2 project.

```
$tile-margin: 20px;
$tile-width: 200px;
$tile-height: 250px;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to write a service which would load the raw scss file using `Http.get`, then pass the results through a regex which matches the variable definitions, but...

But honestly, I think you're barking up the wrong tree and need to rethink the design. Why do you want to apply the styles manually if you've already got the scss variables (and the CSS classes that use them) compiled and available in the client?

Why can't you define your own CSS classes which map to your grid system and then setting up a binding to the host elements `class` in order to bind them? It's a bit ugly, since `ngClass` is a directive, so can't be bound on a host element, but it's doable.

Taking the bootstrap `col-<sw>-<colspan>` format as an example:

```js
 export type ScreenWidth = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';

 @Directive({
   selector: `div[gridColumn]`,
   host: {
     '[attr.class]': 'hostClasses.join(' ')'
   },
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
 })
 export class GridColumn {
   @Input('gridColumn') screenWidth: ScreenWidth = 'md';
   @Input() colSpan: number = 1;

   constructor(private _host: ElementRef) {}

   get hostClasses(): Array<string> {
     let existingClasses = this._host.nativeElement.classList
            .filter(cls => !/^col-/.test(cls)
     return [
        ...existingClasses,
        `col-${this.screenWidth}-${colSpan}`
     ];
   }
 }
```

Usage would then be:

```
 <div gridColumn="xs" [colSpan]="4"></div>
```

Which honestly, is about the same readability as `<div class="col-xs-4"></div>` anyway, so why bother?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using a very non-standard grid. Not all tiles are 1x1, so I'm adding CSS classes such as left-2 and top-3 to apply to the tile elements to arrange them in an order that fits best. If I ever decide to change the tile width or margin width, I don't want to have the code in multiple places.

Comment: Please also note that the raw SCSS files are also bundled out by WebPack

Comment: Ah I see.

I'd still got with defining my own SCSS classes and dynamically binding them to the host  using a directive though. Then you not only have all your code in the one place, but you also have all your styles in stylesheets, where they belong.

Also, you'll be able to apply your existing media queries to them, which is always useful when defining a grid.